# How to initialize a structure containing array of union

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

Here I am having a structure containing a array of unions as

```
typedef struct SCFDummyNode {
  union UDummyProperty {
    float cfpFVal;
    uInt32 cfpUval;
  } property[4];
} CFDummyNode;
```

For this I am initializing in this way as

```
static CFDummyNode Section11DummyData = {{5.0,200.0,63.5,1000.0}};
```

This is giving some errors. Please provide me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors you get? what's `uInt32`?

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 4):

The code gives warnings about missing braces, but doesn't do anything unexpected.

If you want to fix the warning (which you should), use three nested levels of braces:

```
static CFDummyNode Section11DummyData = {
    {{5.0}, {200.0}, {63.5}, {1000.0}}
};
```

The outer braces are for the struct, the next brace level is for the struct member array `property` and the innermost braces are for the unions.

Comment: The OP says that there are errors, however. The code will still compile even without proper brace placement.